# Ext js 7 modern, form.submit vs ajax.request

Tags: javascript, php, extjs, extjs7

I have a Ext.form.Panel with multiple textareafield and fileinput like this

```
// https://requestbin.com/r/en0ej96odon2sm/1n6r1tb49KK6eObGMPHlYa1hh4C

Ext.create({
    xtype: 'formpanel',
    renderTo: document.body,
    buttons: {
        submit: 'onSubmit',
    },

    controller: {

        onSubmit: function () {
            var form = this.getView();

            form.submit({
                method: 'POST',
                url: 'https://en0ej96odon2sm.x.pipedream.net/test1',
                success: function () {}
            });
        },

        onSubmitTest: function () {
            var form = this.getView();
            Ext.Ajax.request({
                url: 'https://en0ej96odon2sm.x.pipedream.net/test2',
                method: 'POST',
                params: {
                    data: form.getValues(),
                },
                success: function () {}
            });
        },

    },

    items: [{
        xtype: 'textareafield',
        name: 'testfield',
        label: 'testfield',
        value: 'test\nasd',
    }, {
        xtype: 'filefield',
        label: 'Upload Test',
        name: 'basedata-test',
    }, {
        xtype: 'button',
        text: 'Ajax.request(), linebreaks but no files',
        handler: 'onSubmitTest',
    }]
});
```

Post Results:
https://requestbin.com/r/en0ej96odon2sm/1n6mtu8QtyreaisCAmV3csO724Q

Fiddle:
https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/3b9j

So, cause i need fileinput/multipart, I have to use form.submit({}).

But when I do so, I don't get the linebreaks on Server side in my $_POST Var.

When I do a ajax.request({}) everything looks good, but $_FILES are missing, so this is not really an option. (but this is documented).

I also tried adding jsonSubmit to the form (then I get no $_POST at all).
When I add enableSubmissionForm: false I get the newline, but after submit the form disappears (and I don't know why).

Is there a solution for this or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following override. Hope it will not make the framework unstable ;)

```
// https://requestbin.com/r/en0ej96odon2sm/1n6r1tb49KK6eObGMPHlYa1hh4C

// Override
Ext.define('overrides.form.Panel', {
    override: 'Ext.form.Panel',
    privates: {
        createSubmissionForm: function (form, values) {
            var fields = this.getFields(),
                name, input, field, fileTrigger, inputDom;

            if (form.nodeType === 1) {
                form = form.cloneNode(false);

                for (name in values) {
                    input = document.createElement('textarea');
                    input.setAttribute('type', 'string');
                    input.setAttribute('name', name);
                    input.innerHTML = values[name];
                    form.appendChild(input);
                }
            }

            for (name in fields) {
                if (fields.hasOwnProperty(name)) {
                    field = fields[name];

                    if (field.isFile) {
                        // The <input type="file"> of a FileField is its "file" trigger button.
                        fileTrigger = field.getTriggers().file;
                        inputDom = fileTrigger && fileTrigger.getComponent().buttonElement.dom;

                        if (inputDom) {
                            if (!form.$fileswap) {
                                form.$fileswap = [];
                            }

                            input = inputDom.cloneNode(true);
                            inputDom.parentNode.insertBefore(input, inputDom.nextSibling);
                            form.appendChild(inputDom);
                            form.$fileswap.push({
                                original: inputDom,
                                placeholder: input
                            });
                        }
                    } else if (field.isPassword) {
                        if (field.getInputType() !== 'password') {
                            field.setRevealed(false);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            return form;
        }
    }
});

Ext.create({
    xtype: 'formpanel',
    renderTo: document.body,
    buttons: {
        submit: 'onSubmit',
    },

    controller: {

        onSubmit: function () {
            var form = this.getView();

            form.submit({
                method: 'POST',
                url: 'https://en0ej96odon2sm.x.pipedream.net/test1',
                success: function () {}
            });
        },

        onSubmitTest: function () {
            var form = this.getView();
            Ext.Ajax.request({
                url: 'https://en0ej96odon2sm.x.pipedream.net/test2',
                method: 'POST',
                params: {
                    data: form.getValues(),
                },
                success: function () {}
            });
        },

    },

    items: [{
        xtype: 'textareafield',
        name: 'testfield',
        label: 'testfield',
        value: 'test\nasd',
    }, {
        xtype: 'filefield',
        label: 'Upload Test',
        name: 'basedata-test',
    }, {
        xtype: 'button',
        text: 'Ajax.request(), linebreaks but no files',
        handler: 'onSubmitTest',
    }]
});
```

Comment: this seems to work, but is it really best practise to add a override for this basic task?

Comment: No, but it looks like to be a bug, which must be fixed. 

Comment: when i read it correct, every field will get send as textarea not as imput anymore? will this break for example number fields? i have to try ...

Answer (score 1):

Not ideal, but you also can do this:

```
form.submit({
            method: 'POST',

            //just like the ajax
            params: {
                data: form.getValues(),
            },
            url: 'https://en0ej96odon2sm.x.pipedream.net/test1',
            success: function () {}
        });
```

Comment: this should work but i have a really huge form, so there is alot of overhead

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple workaround for using Ajax.request instead of form.submit

I needed that because I have to set an Authorization header, which can't be done with IFRAME used by the framework

So preventing Ext.data.request.Ajax from setting `Content-Type` header seems to do the job.

`multipart/form-data` will be automatically set.

Warning : neither `options.headers` nor `defaultHeaders` should already have the 'Content-Type' header

```
Ext.define('Override.data.request.Ajax', {
  override: 'Ext.data.request.Ajax',
  setupHeaders: function(xhr, options, data, params) {
    if (data instanceof FormData) {
      if (Ext.apply({}, options.headers || {}, this.defaultHeaders).hasOwnProperty('Content-Type')) {
        console.warn('The Content-Type header must not be set before request if you need to use FormData with this override');
      }
      /* prevent Ext.data.request.Ajax from setting Content-Type header */
      return this.callParent([xhr, options, null, null]);
    } else {
      return this.callParent(arguments);
    }
  }
});
```

And call Ajax.request with a FormData as `rawData`

```
var formData = new FormData();
var files = myView.down('filefield').getFiles();
if (files.length > 0) {
  formData.append('file', files[0], files[0].name);
}
Ext.Ajax.request({
  url: 'your_url',
  rawData: formData,
  success: function(response) {
    // handle success
  },
  failure: function(response) {
    // handle failure
  }
});
```